# "Hacking- The Art of Exploitation" - incosistencies in memory segmentation

Tags: c, memory-management, buffer

I'm currently studying "Hacking- The Art of Exploitation". There is the code called auth_overflow.c :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int check_authentication(char *password) {
    int auth_flag = 0;
    char password_buffer[16];

    strcpy(password_buffer, password);

    if(strcmp(password_buffer, "brillig")==0)
        auth_flag = 1;
    if(strcmp(password_buffer, "outgrabe")==0)
        auth_flag = 1;

    return auth_flag;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if(argc < 2) {
        printf("Usage: %s <password>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(0);
    }
    if(check_authentication(argv[1])) {
        printf("\n-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-\n");
        printf("        ACCESS GRANTED!\n");
        printf("-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-\n");
    }else{
        printf("\nAccess Denied.\n");
    }
}
```

The program is vulnerable to the argument "A"x30 because of the order of the 'auth_flag' and 'password_buffer' in memory. According to the book, this change should do the fix:

```
    char password_buffer[16];
    int auth_flag = 0;
```

But in my case, it still behave in the same way. After looking in gdb I've noticed that in both programs the 'auth_flag' is in lower memory address comparing to 'password_buffer', no matter which code do I use.
What causes that problem? Is that because of using newer compiler? 
My system version: 4.19.0-kali4-amd64

And while I'm here..
I really enjoy studying this book but I'm aware of many inconsistencies with newer tools and systems. Is there any similar, newer book worth recommending, etc?

Comment: Why `strcpy`? You can use `strncpy` instead with size 16. That will ensure that no matter how long `password` is, in `password_buffer` only 16 characters will be copied.

Comment: The order may matter if you are using unsafe functions like `strcpy` and `strcmp`. But, you can impose restrictions by using safer functions like `strncpy` and `strncmp`. So even if you declare `auth_flag` first or later, it shouldn't matter. See [demo](https://ideone.com/OtYEqi)

Comment: I know that there are safer ways of creating this program but this is not the case. This code is copied from book and the thing that I want to know is why the order of variables in memory is the same for both versions of this program. The author says that in second versions of program, 'password_buffer' is supposed to be below 'auth_flag'. Which is somehow false for me.

Comment: @kiner_shah the book is hacking, and in this case demonstrating a consequence of overflowing a buffer (in this case overwriting a local variable).  Using something like `strncpy` or checking size of input, etc. would hide what this example is trying to demonstrate.

Comment: @KacperPaluch   As I recall, the compiler is free to layout local variables in any manner it likes.  Newer version of gcc might layout variables differently than what the book used (the book is a bit old, but still quite valuable) so it could have used an older version of gcc.  The suggestions would be (1) turn off any optimizations that the compile might be using -O0 (that's a capitol 'O' followed by a zero) or possiblye -Og (2) check to see what version of gcc the books authors used (probably in the introduction) and use that

Comment: @thurizas Thank you, I'll stick to that solution for now.

Comment: @thurizas, I got that the point of book was to show the effect of overflow and how to avoid such bugs, however, my point was that order of declaring variables doesn't matter. Changing the order to avoid the overflow doesn't make sense. Instead to avoid it, one must use safer mechanisms like `strncpy`.